# Does Bluetooth Latency come from the Transmitter or receiver?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, latency

I'm going to buy a [low-latency Bluetooth module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MTFRKQM) that functions both as a transmitter as both receiver. Should I get just one to connect to my audio interface or do I also need one for my headphones if I want to minimize latency?

The aforementioned module used aptX technology, making it much faster than standard Bluetooth (which my headphones use).

Comment: if the module has lower latency than your headphones, then use the module, otherwise use the headphones without the module ... you are asking a technical question about unknown devices

Answer (score 0):

To begin, aptX is an algorithm that is used to compress-decompress sounds on the fly; this is often called codecs [short for coder-decoder]. It is similar mp3, mp4, and wav algorithms but these are intended to be **embedded in the hardware itself**. Therefore, one can conclude that there could be less delay in some codecs, but it is not really detectable by humans. However, the quality of the sound might be more **noticeable** than the delay.

At the end, aptX or no aptX you are still using Bluetooth. And yes, aptX might improve your audio a few percentage points but the aptX might just be **marketing propaganda.**